# Ошибка с конструктором в js. в хроме работает,а через chrome.pak нет

Tags: javascript, blob

Есть сборка браузера,созданная для показа информации с сайта создателя программы.
используем элемент chromium(chrome.pak).
JS код работает в нем исправно,но до того момента,как я хочу подгрузить blob обьект.
Ругается на строчку

```
var out = window.URL.createObjectURL(new blob([data]);
```

ошибка illegal constructor.
в хроме,яндекс лисе браузерах работает нормально.

Comment: Что за `blob`? Я знаю только `Blob`.

Comment: он самый. есть идеи почему так происходит?

Comment: Первый же вопрос из гугла на тему: [Тык ми](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19779153/6275986) и там возникла проблема из-за неправильного регистра. Совпадение? Не думаю.

Comment: не дожал шифт. проблема в том ,что мой браузер не поддерживает ни Blob ни blobbuilder/